# Qt - How to catch keyboard event in line edit?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I catch a `return` press keyboard event in a line edit in Qt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the `returnPressed` signal.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#returnPressed

Answer (score 0):

For all who want to catch another keyboard events - use `eventFilter`.
(In case of `return` and `QLineEdit` Andrew's answer is better than mine).